# How do I fix this error? Argument 1: cannot convert 'string' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'

Tags: c#, string, error-handling, dbcontext

I have a problem with `DbContext`. I decided to make a new class, which will be responsible for the connections with the Database.

```
public class DataContextService : IDataContextService
    {
        private IMediator _mediator { get; }
        private CommonContext _commonContext { get; set; }
        private MembershipContext _membershipContext { get; set; }
        private LogsContext _logContext { get; set; }
        private MongoContext _mongoContext { get; set; }
        private IServiceScopeFactory _scopeService;
```

However, I have an exception near the name of base:

> Argument 1: cannot convert 'string' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'.

I found a similar issue and response with code similar to mine, but I am not sure how to fix this issue. I would appreciate your help.

```
internal MembershipContext Membership_Context
        {
            get
            {
                if (_membershipContext == null)
                {
                     //This is where the error happens
                    _membershipContext = new MembershipContext(AwsSecretsManager.Get(AwsSecretNames.DbsMembership, "BusinessObjects")); 
                }
                return _membershipContext;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I do understand what you mean. I fixed the question  so that instead of images you can see the actual code. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Which line in the code throws error? Code of `DataContextService` is not complete. What is `MembershipContext`? where that comes in to picture?

Comment: Right well I modified the text to show where the error happens.

Answer (score 1):

I found how to fix the error. I was missing the definition for `DBContextOptions` inside the `MembershipContext`. I just had to add it so that the method could recognize the connection string.

Inside `MembershipContext.cs`:

```
 private static DbContextOptions GetOptions(string connectionString)
        {
            return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), connectionString, o => o.CommandTimeout(300)).Options;
        }
        public MembershipContext(string connectionString) : base(GetOptions(connectionString))
        {

        }
```